# How to use stochRsi in Pine script v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I used stochRsi same as Rsi function. Rsi works fine but I'm getting error on stochRsi part.
why? and what is the correct way to use stochRsi?

I want to plotshape on chart when cross of stochRsi occurs.

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
import TradingView/ta/5
plotshape(ta.crossover(ta.rsi(close,14),70))
plotshape(ta.crossover(ta.stochRsi(14,5,14,5,close),70))
```

Answer (score 0):

ta.stochRsi returns:
([float, float]) A tuple of the slow %K and the %D moving average values.

For example:
[k, d] = ta.stochRsi(14,5,14,5,close)